# issue: Change tab before loading data in tabcontent

Tags: android

I have issue when I to do tabhost in android.
it's. I have 3 tabs But when I change tabs, I feeling it's very slowly and annoy. Because each tab content. I loading data by json from server. I think It's reason for slowly.

So, I have question: How Can I change tab before loading data ? Who can know or Can fix the issue. Can give me a solution.

Thanks you so much ! !

Cheers ! !

Comment: show only a loading icon when you create the view. Call a parallel asynctask or intentservice to do the fetching for u, update the screen after those network tasks finishes. You might want to do some research on LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: Yes ! Thank you for recommend. I will find LocalBroadcastManager and discover it !